# Google App Engine Cron Requests Using POST

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

Is it possible to make a cron request to a URL via Google App Engine using `method=post`. I could not find anything in the documentation allowing different methods other than `get`.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#Python_app_yaml_Cron_support_in_the_development_server

Comment: What would be the value of that.  If you want more/complex information store it in the datastore and fetch it when running the cron.

Comment: @TimHoffman because GET requests can be cached by browsers and by infrastructure between the user and the server. GET requests can also be invoked by browsers unintentionally (i.e., look-ahead pre-caching). GET is inappropriate for this type of thing. Google should have use POST or at least made it an option.

Answer (score 8):

the simple answer is no. from the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) it is clearly stated that cron jobs use HTTP GET. the best thing is to change your method to GET and restrict direct access to the url in your app.yaml.
like this:

```
handlers:
 - url: /report/weekly
   script: reports.app
   login: admin
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. The requests will have a header 'X-AppEngine-Cron' that you can check for, that might help if you want to prevent accidental running from a browser.